# JAXB Unmarshalling X,X*

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I am having a problem unmarshalling this class from XML.

The problem is caused by the two elements called 'propertyset'. What actually happens is that the first propertyset is unmarshalled correctly then it is immediately overwritten with the second, if it exists...

Is there any annotation/configuration that I can use to successfully unmarshal this XML?

```
/**
 * <p>Java class for a element declaration.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * <element name="a">
 *   <complexType>
 *     <complexContent>
 *       <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *         <sequence>
 *           <element ref="propertyset"/>
 *           <element ref="propertyset" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         </sequence>
 *         <attribute name="id" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}long" />
 *         <attribute name="description" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *       </restriction>
 *     </complexContent>
 *   </complexType>
 * </element>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "propertyset",
    "systempropertyset"
}, factoryMethod = "createAEx", factoryClass = ObjectFactoryEx.class)
@XmlRootElement(name = "a")
public class A
{
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = B.class)
    protected B propertyset;
    @XmlElement(name = "propertyset", type = B.class)
    protected B systempropertyset;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now moved on to using Moxy. With this I can use @XmlPath("propertyset[1]") and @XmlPath("propertyset[2]")

This works as advertised!